# How RxJS pipe works (lettable operators)

Tags: rxjs5

This is actually note to self but it could be useful for others.

So, here's 2 pieces of code and my question in gitter:

What's the difference between those two?:

````
    @Effect()
    loadRegistrationsFailed$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(registrations.LOAD_FAIL)
        .pipe(
            map(
                action =>
                    new ShowErrorDialogAction({
                        correlationId: new Guid(),
                        title: "Server is unreachable",
                        message:
                            "Can't load user registrations. Can't connect to the server"
                    })
            )
        );
```
and
```
    @Effect()
    loadRegistrationsFailed$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(registrations.LOAD_FAIL)
        .pipe(action =>
            of(
                new ShowErrorDialogAction({
                    correlationId: new Guid(),
                    title: "Server is unreachable",
                    message:
                        "Can't load user registrations. Can't connect to the server"
                })
            )
        );
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Brandt B., here's the answer:

> its related to how the pipe function works. pipe reduces the array of functions passed to it. In the previous value it executes the map function which stores the function you passed to the map internally. In the second example it executes the action=> of immediatly and returns it as the result of the pipe. Therefore the result of the entire observable is of(action) which gets subscribed to by the effect library which produces the value immediately

---

The answer from Dorus on the same question:

The difference between those two samples is the the first one will map the values, where the second one will just replace the entire thing with of and ignore anything emitted by the source.

The correct way to write the second one would be

```
@Effect()
loadRegistrationsFailed$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(registrations.LOAD_FAIL)
    .pipe(ob => ob.mergeMap(action =>
        of(
            new ShowErrorDialogAction({
                correlationId: new Guid(),
                title: "Server is unreachable",
                message:
                    "Can't load user registrations. Can't connect to the server"
            })
        ))
    );
```

Since you dont use action, you could also use mergeMapTo or mepTo:

```
@Effect()
loadRegistrationsFailed$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(registrations.LOAD_FAIL)
    .pipe(ob => ob.mergeMapTo(of(
            new ShowErrorDialogAction({
                correlationId: new Guid(),
                title: "Server is unreachable",
                message:
                    "Can't load user registrations. Can't connect to the server"
            })
        ))
    );
```

The only thing lettable operators add is that you can write .pipe(map()) instead of .pipe(ob => ob.map())